# Angular tutorial - HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule returning 404 from api/heroes

Tags: angular

Stumped here. I must be missing something. I've followed the Angular tutorial up to part 6, which implements the HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule, to mock the hero service backend. When I load the page, though, the console shows a 404 error contacting the url at api/heroes. Anyone have any idea what I've done wrong or how I can get past this?

**app.module.ts:**

```typescript
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes/heroes.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail/hero-detail.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';

import { HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService } from './in-memory-data.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    MessagesComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
      InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
    ),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**in-memory-data.service.ts:**

```typescript
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { Hero } from './hero'
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {

  createDb() {
    const heroes = [
      { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
      { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
      { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
      { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
      { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
      { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
      { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
      { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
      { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
      { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
    ];
    return heroes;
  }

  genId(heroes: Hero[]): number {
    return heroes.length > 0 ? Math.max(...heroes.map(hero => hero.id)) + 1 : 11;
  }
}
```

**hero.service.ts:**

```typescript
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';
import { Hero } from './hero';
//import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes'; // URL to in-memory heroes resource

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private messageService: MessageService
    ) { }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    //this.log('HeroService: fetched heroes');
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(this.heroesUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log('fetched heroes')),
        catchError(this.handleError<Hero[]>('getHeroes', []))
      );
  }

  getHero(id: number) : Observable<Hero> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get<Hero>(url)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => this.log(`fetched hero id=${id}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError<Hero>(`getHero id=${id}`))
      );
  }

  private log(message: string) {
    this.messageService.add(`HeroService: ${message}`);
  }

  private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

      console.error(error);

      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);

      // Return empty result to let the app keep running
      return of(result as T);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, death by the tiniest of mistakes!

In **in-memory-data.service.ts**, I fixed this by changing line 23 inside the createDb function:

```typescript
return heroes;
```

to:

```typescript
return { heroes };
```

Sigh. Time to drink more coffee and leave this answer here for posterity.